# How to make the style setter data property dynamically in wpf (style is not in the main window xaml it is separate xaml)

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, styles, setter

How di I make the style setter data property dynamically in wpf (style is not in the main window xaml it is separate xaml)

```html
 <Style x:Key="Room3HZ"
        TargetType="Path"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource DrawingItemStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Data"
                Value="M 17,70 L 550,70 551,331 17,331 17,70 195,70 195,330 367,330  367,69"/>
    </Style>
```

This code is in DrawingStencils.xaml page
how to dynamically set the data in mainwindow.xmal.cs page?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, I believe you are asking how to use a WPF Style defined in one XAML file from another XAML file.

What you need to do is reference the XAML style file (DrawingStencils.xaml) in the MainWindow.xaml file as a ResourceDictionary and then apply the style to the target type using the StaticResource keyword.

**Are you sure you want to apply this style to type Path?**

Shown below is a simple style for Button which is defined is separate file (Styles.xaml) and then referenced in the MainView.xaml file:

Styles.xaml file:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle"
           TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Red" />        
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

MainView.xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="StyleExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>

        <Button Content="My Button"
                Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now how can i specify the path Data i.e(<Setter Property="Data"
                Value="M 17,70 L 550,70 551,331 17,331 17,70 195,70 195,330 367,330  367,69"/>) from code behind

Comment: you can do it from code behind, but you should really only want to do this in XAML

Comment: And why is that ? then how can i change the data dynamically (here it is an  shape), the data are co-ordinates to draw the shape.

Comment: if you want to change a shape in the UI you would use an animation to do this, how this is trigger is down to your requirements, but you need to invesitgate how to create animation in XAML in WPF.